# Get Count in Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to get the count of the same article_id inside the 'likes' table

**article.php model**

```
public function like()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Like', 'id', 'article_id');
}
```

Currently this is my query

```
    $mentor = $this->article->with("articlecategory")->with("user")->with(['like' => function ($query) use ($qUserId) {
        $query->where("user_id", $qUserId);
    }])->orderby("id", "DESC")->get();
```

IT returns something this:

```
{
   "id":66,
   "user_id":317,
   "cat_id":4,
   "title":"a",
   "photo":"",
   "content":"a",
   "created_at":"2020-05-29 19:01:12",
   "updated_at":"2020-05-29 19:01:12",
   "articlecategory":{
      "id":4,
      "title":"Financial",
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null
   },
   "user":{
      "id":317,
      "state_id":null,
      "city_id":null,
      "category_id":10,
      "sub_cat_id":0,
      "name":"jeff2",
      "mname":null,
      "lname":"benzos2",
      "gender":null,
      "email":"jeff@gmail.com",
      "phone":"11111111111",
      "telephone":null,
      "role":"Mentor",
      "salaryrange":null,
      "ccode":null,
      "fbmsg":null,
      "skype":null,
      "viber":null,
      "activate":1,
      "about":"222a\naasd\n\na",
      "fbmsg_user":null,
      "skype_user":null,
      "viber_user":null,
      "expr":null,
      "skill":null,
      "education":null,
      "cover":"",
      "bdate":null,
      "facebookurl":null,
      "twitterurl":null,
      "linkedurl":null,
      "googleurl":null,
      "youtubeurl":null,
      "pnp":null,
      "pnpfile":"0",
      "sss":null,
      "sssfile":"0",
      "barangay":null,
      "nbi":null,
      "tin":"0",
      "last_lat":null,
      "last_long":null,
      "last_locality":"",
      "created_at":"2020-03-23 11:59:23",
      "updated_at":"2020-06-16 06:11:00"
   },
   "like":{
      "id":4,
      "user_id":177,
      "article_id":66,
      "like_count":1,
      "created_at":"2020-06-28 14:41:10",
      "updated_at":"2020-06-28 15:59:44"
   }
}
```

I would like to have the total likes of the 'articleID'

Can I call the table 'Likes' again to get the count? But how? Im lost.

I would like to add another array after the 'like' array like:

```
"like":{
          "id":4,
          "user_id":177,
          "article_id":66,
          "like_count":1,
          "created_at":"2020-06-28 14:41:10",
          "updated_at":"2020-06-28 15:59:44"
       },
"total_article_likes":{
        "count":"3"
}
```

EDIT**
or maybe any kind of array, as long as I can get the total count of the likes in the article_id

Edit**

I got this query

```
 $mentor = $this->article->with("articlecategory")->with("user")->with(['like' => function ($query) use ($qUserId) {
        $query->where("user_id", $qUserId);
    }])->withCount(["like"])->orderby("id", "DESC")->get();
```

It does the job, but I need to filter it to where like_count = 1, how can I filter it?

Comment: What is the like_count in like about? Different users can like an article, so that the total_article_likes value is the same whatever user is used to run the query? If that is true I assume that doing it with another query filtered by the article_id is an easy solution.

Comment: Hi, I answered my question but it seems like it wasnt the one i want, I got this query:  $mentor = $this->article->with("articlecategory")->with("user")->with(['like' => function ($query) use ($qUserId) {
        $query->where("user_id", $qUserId);
    }])->withCount(["like"])->orderby("id", "DESC")->get(); but I need to filter it more, how can I filter it?

Comment: I updated the question, I need to filter the withCount, is there any way?

Comment: What about filtering the like_count in the subquery $query->where("user_id", $qUserId)->where('like_count',1);

Comment: use sum eloquent query with DB::raw

Comment: you can add the constraints to `withCount` just like `with`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on subqueries like `withCount` - it generates a subquery - using the `having` clause, like this:

```php
$this->article
     ->with("articlecategory")
     ->with("user")
     ->with(['like' => function ($query) use ($qUserId) {
         $query->where("user_id", $qUserId);
     }])->withCount(["like"])
     ->having('like_count','=',1) 
     ->orderby("id", "DESC")->get();
```